# Cannot install R package "expm"

Tags: r

I'm using R 3.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit) - on Linux Mint.
Trying to launch **Rkward** app, while import of CSV file it fails:

```
Loading required package: ltm
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘ltm
```

After trying to install **ltm** package it fails because it depends on **msm** package, which depends on **expm** package:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'expm.so' failed
make: *** [expm.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘expm’
* removing ‘/home/amddred/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/expm’
ERROR: dependency ‘expm’ is not available for package ‘msm’
* removing ‘/home/amddred/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/msm’
ERROR: dependency ‘msm’ is not available for package ‘ltm’
* removing ‘/home/amddred/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ltm’
```

What can be done to solve this?

In the end I'd like to see if Rkward can give me other result than JASP or GNU PSPP, that are computing kinda awkward results of Cronbach's alpha.

Comment: Is there another error message above those lines?

Comment: Start by installing `r-base-dev` -- you are missing some `-dev` packages needed to compile from source.  Then install one by one, if need be, starting with `expm`.

Comment: `compilation failed for package ‘expm’`: It looks like there was a compilation problem. You're using linux? What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! `r-base-dev` installation has helped!